# How to return to the beginning of menu in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, console

`I am writing a program for my computer science class and for whatever reason cannot get it to return the programs original menu after completing a task.

I need the program to go back to the original menu and not just stop after completing an option. Ive tried adding a while loop and a for loop to the beginning of the program but it does not fix it. Should be a simple fix but idk what it is. Thanks.

```
import javax.lang.model.type.ArrayType;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.util.ArrayList; //import the arrayList class
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static ArrayList<String> planets = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //Default values, can leave blank or remove
        planets.add(0, "Mars");
        planets.add(1, "Jupiter");
        planets.add(2, "Earth");
        planets.add(3, "Venus");
        planets.add(4, "Neptune");
        planets.add(5, "Saturn");
        boolean isactive;
        if (isactive =true) {
            System.out.println("Choose your favorite planets with this program. This program edits arrays, please choose an array position to edit [0,1,2,3]");
            System.out.println("1. Print Array");
            System.out.println("2. Edit Array");
            System.out.println("3. Add to array");
            System.out.println("4. Exit the program");

            ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            int MenuOption = scn.nextInt(); //Scan result

            if (MenuOption == 1) {
                System.out.println(planets);
            }

            if (MenuOption == 2) {
                System.out.println("Please choose which element to edit");
                System.out.println("0");
                System.out.println("1");
                System.out.println("2");
                System.out.println("3");
                System.out.println("4");
                System.out.println("5");
                System.out.println("6");
                System.out.println("7");
                System.out.println("Press 9 to exit");


                Scanner editMenu = new Scanner(System.in);
                int editMenuOption = editMenu.nextInt();
                if (editMenuOption == 0) {
                    System.out.println("what would you like to change position 0 to");
                    Scanner posZeroScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String posZeroScanEdit = posZeroScan.next();
                    planets.add(0, posZeroScanEdit);
                    System.out.println(planets);


                }

                if (editMenuOption == 1) {
                    System.out.println("what would you like to change position 1 to");
                    Scanner posOneScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String posOneScanEdit = posOneScan.next();
                    planets.add(1, posOneScanEdit);
                    System.out.println(planets);
                }

                if (editMenuOption == 2) {
                    System.out.println("what would you like to change position 2 to");
                    Scanner posTwoScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String posTwoScanEdit = posTwoScan.next();
                    planets.add(2, posTwoScanEdit);
                    System.out.println(planets);
                }

                if (editMenuOption == 3) {
                    System.out.println("what would you like to change position 3 to");
                    Scanner posThreeScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String posThreeScanEdit = posThreeScan.next();
                    planets.add(3, posThreeScanEdit);
                    System.out.println(planets);

                }

                if (editMenuOption == 4) {
                    System.out.println("what would you like to change position 4 to");
                    Scanner posFourScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String posFourScanEdit = posFourScan.next();
                    planets.add(4, posFourScanEdit);
                    System.out.println(planets);

                }

                if (editMenuOption == 5) {
                    System.out.println("what would you like to change position 4 to");
                    Scanner posFiveScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String posFiveScanEdit = posFiveScan.next();
                    planets.add(5, posFiveScanEdit);
                    System.out.println(planets);

                }

                if (editMenuOption == 6) {
                    System.out.println("what would you like to change position 4 to");
                    Scanner posSixScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String posSixScanEdit = posSixScan.next();
                    planets.add(6, posSixScanEdit);
                    System.out.println(planets);

                }

                if (editMenuOption == 7) {
                    System.out.println("what would you like to change position 4 to");
                    Scanner posSevenScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String posSevenScanEdit = posSevenScan.next();
                    planets.add(7, posSevenScanEdit);
                    System.out.println(planets);

                } else {
                    System.exit(1);
                }

            }

            if (MenuOption == 3) {
                System.out.println("What would you like to add");
                Scanner add = new Scanner(System.in);
                String addRes = add.next();

                planets.add(addRes);
                System.out.println(planets);


            }

            if (MenuOption == 4) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for checking out my program!");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using only the main-method, I assume you want to repeat the main-method from the beginning. In that case, you can simply call it like this:

```
main(null);
```

Comment: that feels like memory leak anti pattern

Comment: You mean because there could be code after the main-call? That might happen indeed - if you actually write code after the main-call. Otherwise it reminds me more of recursive self-calling. Even if it's not really recursion.

Comment: Yea, it is recursion which is why I said that it is anti pattern while we talking about loading another instance of entire program. In op example that of course wouldn't be much of an issue because there isn't a lot of data but if you think in bigger scope. You would possible run a few applications in itself so let's say that one app would use 40mb of ram then after calling main(null) it would use 80 and so on

Answer (score 0):

This line `if (isactive =true)` you have to replace it with a loop.
For example you can replace with `while (isactive =true)` and isactive must be initialized with **true**

Answer (score 0):

Initialize isactive: `boolean isactive = true;`

change if to while-loop: `while(isactive)` instead of `if(isactive =true)`
and modify Option 4

```
if (MenuOption == 4) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for checking out my program!");
                isactive=false;
            }
```